# Ruby - can you tell me whats going on here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Confused by this method - can someone please explain it to me?

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= (login_from_session || login_from_cookie) unless @current_user == false
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says:

1. unless current is not set (the latest unless)
2. do nothing and return `@current_user` if `@current_user` is already set (the `||=` part)
3. else call the method/helper `login_from_session` and assign the result to `@current_user`
4. else if the previous call has returned `nil` or `false`, call the method/helper `login_from_cookie` and assign the result to `@current_user`
5. in any case return the value of `@current_user` instance variable

It could be rewritten to be more explicit in this way

```
def current_user
  if !(@current_user == false) # 1
    if (@current_user)
      return @current_user # 2
    end
    if (@current_user = login_from_session)
      return @current_user # 3
    end
    if (@current_user = login_from_cookie)
      return @current_user # 4
    end  
  end
  return @current_user # 5
end
```

This is the power (and the beauty) of ruby expressiveness. Remember that in Ruby only `nil` and `false` evaluate to boolean false in if/else statements and `||`, `&&` operators

Other hints to understand better, in ruby you have the following rules:

The return value of any function is the last expression evaluated for the function, so

```
def foo
  any_value
end
```

is the same of

```
def foo
  return any_value
end
```

The if/unless statement at the end of an expression is the same of a if/unless statement, so

```
do something if value
```

is the same of

```
if (value)
  do_something
end
```

The `||=` operator is a shortcut for

```
@a ||= some_value
# is equivalent to
if !@a
  @a = some_value
end
```

Combine all these rules and you've the method explained.